# Making an alarm with C# to ring on specific constant times, throughout a day

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an alarm to ring on specific times ( for example; every five minutes after 9:30 am till 4 pm). So, I want to write a code that rings in 9:30 and 9:35 and ... . but with every approach ultimately I get an error. in my code I have a string that includes the times, but I cannot use that string or group in a if(...) to make the alarm. it's fine with just one number with var..., where am I wrong?

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;


            string[] DailyTime = { 093000, 093500 };

            if (((currentTime.Hour * 10000)  + (currentTime.Minute *100)  + currentTime.Second) == DailyTime) 
            {
                timer.Stop();
                try 
                {
                    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
                    player.SoundLocation = @"C:\Windows\Media\Time interval alarm\FiveH.wav";
                    player.Play();
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' PM -

Comment: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' PM -

Comment: Error CS0019 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and

Comment: `string[] DailyTime = { 093000, 093500 };` I doubt this compiles. Later on you try to equal this string array to an integer ... no way. Errors totally expected.

Comment: basically in this two line:
string[] DailyTime = { 093000, 093500 };

        if (((currentTime.Hour * 10000)  + (currentTime.Minute *100)  + currentTime.Second) == DailyTime)

Comment: Just to make these errors go away: make `DailyTime` an `int[]`. Then check `DailyTime.Contains()`.

Comment: so what is the right way?

Comment: See above, but there are more issues: You should trigger the timer every 500 ms if you want a resolution of 1 second. And if triggered, you should play the sound not on that thread.

Comment: int[] DailyTime = {150505, 150606 };
            
            if (((currentTime.Hour * 10000)  + (currentTime.Minute *100)  + currentTime.Second) == DailyTime.Contains())

like this?

Comment: now it gives this:
Error CS1501 No overload for method 'Contains' takes 0 arguments

Comment: I don't know which development environment/editor you are using, but it seems you're on something that does not have (IntelliSense, i.e. present you with possible completions for what you are currently typing). Do yourself a favor and use Visual Studio community edition. This will help you a lot with avoiding/directly fixing the most basic errors in your code.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Sorry, i"m really new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 5; //5 minutes
    timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    InitializeTimer(); //this method makes sure the timer starts at the correct time
}
```

The timer initialization method:

```
private async void InitializeTimer()
{
     while (!timer.Enabled) //keep looping until timer is initialized
     {
         //if the minute is a multiple of 5 (:00, :05, ...) start the timer
         if (DateTime.Now.Minute % 5 == 0 && DateTime.Now.Second == 0)
         {
             timer.Start();
             TriggerAlarm(); //trigger the alarm initially instead of having to wait 5min
         }
         else
         {
             await Task.Delay(100);
         }            
     }        
}
```

You could store the times and alarm paths in a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<TimeSpan, string> dict = new Dictionary<TimeSpan, string>()
{
    { new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0), @"C:\Windows\Media\Time interval alarm\FiveH.wav" },
    { new TimeSpan(9, 35, 0), @"C:\Windows\Media\Time interval alarm\Whatever.wav" },
    { new TimeSpan(9, 40, 0), @"C:\Windows\Media\Time interval alarm\Whatever1.wav" },
    { new TimeSpan(9, 45, 0), @"C:\Windows\Media\Time interval alarm\Whatever2.wav" },
    //...
    { new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0), @"C:\Windows\Media\Time interval alarm\Whatever3.wav" }
};
```

The Timer_Elapsed event, which will trigger every 5 min since the alarm is started

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    TriggerAlarm();
}
```

The method that plays the sound

```
private static void TriggerAlarm()
{
    TimeSpan alarmTime = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, 0);
    if (dict.TryGetValue(alarmTime, out string alarmFile))
    {
        using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(alarmFile))
        {
            player.Play();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //this alarm time is not found in the dictionary, 
        //therefore, no alarm should be played at this time (e.g. 16:05:00)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time, but this one ultimately wont work because for example; on the third time, it should play another file.
it works the best if it was a code that on theses times .... play this and on these times play that.

Comment: for example on 9:45 I want the program to play a file that says 15 instead of five,  and then on 9:50 play the previous file that says 5